# Is there a widely accepted 64bit date and time format?

Tags: time, 64-bit

I need precision down to millisecond level. Since I couldn't find anything relevant on google (except for year 2038 and all that), I tried to come up with my own. Lets say i is a 64bit unsigned integer encoded like this

i = milliseconds
i *= 1000
i += seconds
i *= 60
i += minutes
i *= 60
i += hours
i *= 24
i += days
i *= 366
i += year

this would put the end of days to year 583344214 january 10, 2:25:51:616 PM. Far enough. However, if there is an already established 64bit time format with milliseconds, I'd rather go with that. Anything?

Comment: Why can't you use a standard unix timestamp with millisecond precision?

Comment: In what environment? Most have an 8 byte DateTime.

Comment: windows and linux, cross language (all though mostly c++)

Comment: Programmers cannot agree about how to encode text, about as simple as it gets.  That does *not* get better when dealing with time and dates.